# с помощью вложенного цикла напечатать матрицу не используя массив

Tags: c++, c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

задали такую задачку где нужно распечатать с помощью вложенных циклов данные в таблице не испольнуя массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j += 2){
            if (i + j <= 8){
                std::cout << i + j + 2 << " ";
            }
            else{
                std::cout << 20 - i - j - 2<< " ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
        for (int m = 0; m < 5; ++m) {
            if (n + m <= 4)
                cout << setw(5) << (n + m + 1) * 2;
            else
                cout << setw(5) << (9 - n - m) * 2;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
```